# Tinymce Editor changes size on different length of text line

Tags: tinymce

I'm getting a weird problem with TinyMCE.  When I click the cursor to the end, depending on the length of the line the editor may change it's size (width/height).

This doesn't happen with the demos and I can't seem to find how my options radically differ from the defaults.

Here is an example of the same text but different sizes when the cursor is at the end of each line:

[image: 1.]

[image: 2.]

Has anyone else seen this type of behaviour?

My init code as it were:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '/assets/modules/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php',

        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "spellchecker",
        editor_selector : "tinymce",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,forecolor,backcolor,spellchecker",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,

        apply_source_formatting : true,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_retain_style_properties : false,
        paste_strip_class_attributes : true,
        paste_remove_spans : true,
        paste_remove_styles : true,
        paste_remove_styles_if_webkit : true,
        cleanup : true,

        content_css : '/assets/modules/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/myownstyle.css',
```

Comment: does this even happen on the tinymce demo page?

Comment: As I said in the posting.  No this does not happen with the demos.  I think I know what the issue is, but I am experiencing come tech difficulties and can't yet mark the post as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can ascertain looking at this again.

If I have:

```
    apply_source_formatting : false,
    /*paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    paste_retain_style_properties : false,
    paste_strip_class_attributes : true,
    paste_remove_spans : true,
    paste_remove_styles : true,
    paste_remove_styles_if_webkit : true,*/
    cleanup : true,
```

and also

```
 ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            ed.pasteAsPlainText = true; 
        });
```

Then text comes in unformatted and also does not change the size of the editor when clicking on different parts of the text.

This is fine for me.  I'm not too bothered about capturing the format of the paste.